# Flutter The following LateError was thrown building LayoutBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

the flutter code below shows me the following error, how can I fix it? and what is it due to?

**Error:**

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following LateError was thrown building LayoutBuilder:
LateInitializationError: Field '_interactiveViewerState@1219435804' has not been initialized.
```

**Maps.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:map_launcher/map_launcher.dart';
import 'package:map_launcher/map_launcher.dart' as ml;
import 'package:parking_4xp/pages/dettaglio_parcheggio.dart';

import 'oggetti/obj_parcheggio.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Map Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: MyMapPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyMapPage({Key? key, this.iParcheggi, this.availableMaps})
      : super(key: key);

  final List<AvailableMap>? availableMaps;
  final List<ObjParcheggio>? iParcheggi;

  _MyMapPageState createState() => _MyMapPageState();
}

class _MyMapPageState extends State<MyMapPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Marker> markers = [];
  late MapController mapController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mapController = MapController();
    caricaIMarker();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    mapController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  LatLngBounds boundsFromLatLngList(List<Marker> list) {
    mapController = MapController();
    double x0 = 0.0, x1 = 0.0, y0 = 0.0, y1 = 0.0;
    try {
      for (Marker latLng in list) {

          if (latLng.point.latitude > x1) x1 = latLng.point.latitude;
          if (latLng.point.latitude < x0) x0 = latLng.point.latitude;
          if (latLng.point.longitude > y1) y1 = latLng.point.longitude;
          if (latLng.point.longitude < y0) y0 = latLng.point.longitude;

      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    }

    return LatLngBounds(LatLng(x1, y1), LatLng(x0, y0));
  }

  void _animatedMapMove(
      LatLng destLocation, double destZoom, bool spazioSotto) {
    // Create some tweens. These serve to split up the transition from one location to another.
    // In our case, we want to split the transition be<tween> our current map center and the destination.
    final _latTween = Tween<double>(
        begin: mapController.center.latitude, end: destLocation.latitude);
    final _lngTween = Tween<double>(
        begin: mapController.center.longitude, end: destLocation.longitude);
    final _zoomTween = Tween<double>(begin: mapController.zoom, end: destZoom);

    // Create a animation controller that has a duration and a TickerProvider.
    var controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
    // The animation determines what path the animation will take. You can try different Curves values, although I found
    // fastOutSlowIn to be my favorite.
    Animation<double> animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);

    controller.addListener(() {
      mapController.move(
          LatLng(_latTween.evaluate(animation), _lngTween.evaluate(animation)),
          _zoomTween.evaluate(animation));
    });

    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        controller.dispose();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        controller.dispose();
      }
    });

    controller.forward();
  }

  void caricaIMarker() {
    for (ObjParcheggio park in widget.iParcheggi!) {
      markers.add(Marker(
          point: LatLng(park.latitudine!, park.longitudine!),
          height: 60,
          width: 30,
          child: Container(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _animatedMapMove(
                    LatLng(park.latitudine ?? 0, park.longitudine ?? 0),
                    13,
                    true);

                int totalePostiLiberi = 0;

                for (Area area in park.leAree) {
                  totalePostiLiberi += area.postiLiberi!;
                }

                showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    elevation: 10,
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Container(
                          height: 180,
                          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 10),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  ListTile(
                                    title: Text('${park.descrizione}',
                                        style: Theme.of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .headlineMedium),
                                    subtitle: Text(park.indirizzo!,
                                        style: Theme.of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .bodyMedium),
                                    trailing: Icon(
                                      Icons.circle,
                                      size: 40,
                                      color: totalePostiLiberi > 0 &&
                                              park.stato == 0
                                          ? Colors.green
                                          : Colors.red
                                      // .withAlpha(210)
                                      ,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Divider(),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Wrap(
                                      spacing: 10,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                      alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround,
                                      runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        ElevatedButton.icon(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            vaiAllIndirizzo(park);
                                          },
                                          icon: Icon(
                                              FontAwesomeIcons.locationArrow),
                                          label: Text(
                                            'Indicazioni',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        ElevatedButton.icon(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            // areaPrenotazione = null;

                                            Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      DettaglioPage(
                                                          objParcheggio: park,
                                                          index: 0)),
                                            );
                                          },
                                          icon: Icon(
                                              FontAwesomeIcons.squareParking),
                                          label: Text(
                                            'Sosta qui',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // Text(park.descrizione??'', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,),
                                ],
                              )));
                    });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/icona_parking.png'),
            ),
          )));
    }
  }

  void vaiAllIndirizzo(ObjParcheggio objParcheggio) async {
    var coords =
        ml.Coords(objParcheggio.latitudine!, objParcheggio.longitudine!);
    var title = objParcheggio.descrizione;
    if (widget.availableMaps!.isNotEmpty) {
      await MapLauncher.showDirections(
          mapType: widget.availableMaps!.first.mapType,
          destination: coords,
          destinationTitle: title,
          originTitle: 'La tua posizione');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:  FlutterMap(
        mapController: mapController,
        options: MapOptions(
            interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.pinchZoom |
                InteractiveFlag.drag |
                InteractiveFlag.doubleTapZoom |
                InteractiveFlag.pinchMove,
            zoom: 13.0,
            bounds: boundsFromLatLngList(markers)),
        children: [],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```